# Background object is drawn in front of foreground object in OpenGL?

Tags: opengl, drawing, z-index, glut

For testing purposes let's assume I've draw 2 teapots with `glutSolidTeapot()`, like this:

```
glColor3f(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f); // Red teapot
glutWireTeapot(1.0f);

glColor3f(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f); // Green teapot
glTranslatef(0.0f, 0.0f, 3.0f);
glutWireTeapot(1.0f);
```

The camera is initially located at `(x,y,z) = (0.0f, 0.0f, 5.0f)` and I'm looking at `z = -1` (this is camera position #1). I'm sure you understand that the green teapot is the closest object to the camera and the red one is behind it. The problem is that the red one is drawn like it's in front of the green one, which doesn't look right:

Example: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8WoEn.png

Now, if I move the camera too `(x,y,z) = (0.0f, 0.0f, -5.0f)` and look at `z = 1` (this is camera position #2), I will see the red teapot in front of the green one, this is normal behavior. The red is now the object closest to the camera and the green one is behind the red one. Everything is fine.

Example: https://i.stack.imgur.com/eJvPE.png

I know this has something to do with the order, if I switch the code above (green teapot code first), than it will fix the problem in the camera position #1, but the problem will now be visible in camera position #2.

**Why is this happening and how can I keep the objects behind other objects from being drawn in front, or at all?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to allocate a depth-buffer (you're most likely doing this already) and then use `glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST)`

This is happening because without depth-testing, OpenGL does simply not react to different depths relative to the camera. When you enable depth testing, GL will reject all new pixels/fragments that further away than the current closest.

If you want to move around in your scene, you probably want to clear the depth by adding `GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT` to `glClear`, or else it will remember the closest fragment from the previous frame.

Other than that, your perspective matrix might be malformed. This is especially likely, since the red teapot is drawn in front of the green one, while you draw them such that the green one would overdraw the red one with correct depth buffering. Hence, the depth values themselves are probably bad.

Comment: What exactly is "allocate a depth-buffer"? I already have enabled `GL_DEPTH_TEST`. And in case it makes a difference, I'm also using this: `glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DEPTH | GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGBA);`. What I'm missing then?

Comment: I'm doing that already too, hum... Wait, let me post full working example, it's better than just keep guessing.

Comment: In that case, the `GLUT_DEPTH` should make sure a depth-buffer is allocated. Ok, what's strange is that red is drawn over green, even tho you draw them in that order. Possibly you perspective projection matrix is not correctly set up - can you post the code that does that?

Comment: You're right, I just triple checked and found the problem on `gluPerspective()`, the `zNear` was set to `0.0f` instead of `1.0f` as I normally have. I never thought this would cause such a problem, I only wanted to decrease the near clipping plane.

Comment: @Nazgulled: Read the Notes section of the [manpage](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/gluPerspective.xml).

Answer (score 3):

Probably you haven't enabled Depth Buffer aka z-buffer.
To do this in initialization part add something like this

```
glClearDepth(1.0f);
glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
glDepthFunc(GL_LEQUAL);
```

And before rendering every frame you have to clear this buffer as well using

```
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
```

You could check OpenGL Nehe tutorial for more information http://nehe.gamedev.net/data/lessons/lesson.asp?lesson=01

Comment: Is there a function similar to GL_DEPTH_TEST at  Metal ?