# Objects being rendered infront of others OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl, render, depth

i have just started using c++ and OpenGL after using java and very little LWJGL. i have been following these tutorials http://ogldev.atspace.co.uk/ and around tutorial 13 i started to play around a bit my self. After creating some pyramids and controls to move around i noticed that looking at the objects from one angle they look normal but looking another angle objects behind other objects are being rendered in-front. i have already looked at this question

[Background object is drawn in front of foreground object in OpenGL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5330673/background-object-is-drawn-in-front-of-foreground-object-in-opengl)

and didn't find an answer so now i'm so confused and decided to make a stackoverflow account and ask a question. i would post pictures but i don't have enough reputation so here is a link to them (there are 3 in a zip file)

http://www.mediafire.com/download/hucfisn0jytah7o/Game%20screenshots.zip

[EDIT]

Also i though you might need to know, i am using freeglut and glew (may not be the best choice but i like it) and Visual Studio 2012, Windows 8.1 (just got a new laptop and haven't got windows 7 installation disc)

Comment: Do you have depth testing enabled?

Comment: Nope, but when i do enable it i get a black screen.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It sounds like you need to enable the depth test in opengl:

```
glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
```

Otherwise I would need to see where you set up opengl.

Comment: i did this as well as putting GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT in glClear and it worked, just a silly mistake. thanks

Comment: Ha, don't worry about it. Glad I could help.